# How to insert code into wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In many wordpress blogs, we are seeing the code like below.
[image]

Now I want to put my code also like this? How to do it? is it belongs to any thrid party tool or is it in built comes with wordpress? When I copy and paste the code into blog it looking ugly. Please give me suggestion to make my blog more readable.
Thank you

Answer (score 64, accepted):

*If you are running your blog on Wordpress.com*, you just include the following lines before your code.

```
[sourcecode language="csharp"]
//your code comes here
[/sourcecode]
```

Wordpress.com gives us the facility to avoid worrying about code highlighting. If your code is in between these blocks then it will automatically render as per the language you specified. It can support many languages.

Some of them are..

html

javascript

java

javafx

matlab (keywords only)

objc

perl

php

*If you have a self-hosted site, or one hosted on wordpress.org*, you should  should use the SyntaxHighlighter plugin: [wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter](http://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter).

This is the plugin the WordPress team sourced to create this functionality on wordpress.com

For more information see this [link](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/)

Comment: To be clear, the above code only works on wordpress.com sites, not self-hosted (wordpress.org) installations. Self-hosted sites should use the SyntaxHighlighter plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/ which is the plugin the WordPress team sourced to create this functionality on wordpress.com (according to the above-linked documentation anyway).

Comment: Please include comment of @tyler Hayes in your answer.

Answer (score 19):

### Sorry to say, but with following code you mentioned `WONT WORK`

```
[sourcecode language="csharp"]
//your code comes here
[/sourcecode]
```

So, on [Wordpress Site](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/) to add Code snippet to the wordpress blog is:

```
[code language="javascript"]
//your language script here
[/code]
```

Hope this helped you! :)

Comment: Sheklar talk about wordpress.com

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is some kind of syntax highlighter.
Where the code shows up in your post in a box with the number of lines, etc, correct?

There are some plugins in wordpress for that.

Check out:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/

Hope it helps.
Cheers

Comment: You need to install the plugin and follow the plugin instructions. Are you using a self-hosted wordpress blog, or a blog on wordpress.com?

Answer (score 4):

Adding to SHEKHAR SHETE's answer.

**For inline code blocks:**

Selecting a text and then performing `Alt+Shift+x` will make text like:

```
THIS is an example
```

This will actually sorround the text with `<code></code>`

Writing text inside `` `..` `` is another way

[source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Keyboard_Shortcuts)

Answer (score 2):

Do this if you want to add code in your wordpress post:

Switch to Text from HTML in your wordpress editor, then insert 
    `<code>` 
as starting tag and 
    `</code>` 
as end tag.

This is the only method that works in the latest wordpress at the time I am writing the answer. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Latest:  in edit post, start typing /syntax. Choose SyntaxHighligher. You can change the type of language in the block.

WordPress [Help](https://wordpress.com/support/wordpress-editor/blocks/syntax-highlighter-code-block/)